# Copy content of txt file without opening it

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Is there a way or program to copy content of `.txt` file to clipboard without opening it?

Now I have to `open->ctrl+a->ctrl+c->close`. A little bit annoying if you do it often.

Is there a possible shortcut for this operation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a clipboard utility in Windows called `clip.exe`.

In the command prompt, you can copy the contents of a file to your clipboard using

`clip < file.txt`

This will be useful if you use the command prompt often. If you don't, you can add it to your context menu. I've just tested this out with [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-context-menu-item-to-copy-a-text-file-to-the-clipboard-in-windows-vista/) from HowToGeek on Windows 7, but I had to make a little tweak before I got it to work.

HowToGeek has also mentioned that `clip.exe` does not come with XP, so you'll have to download it from Microsoft FTP [here](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Services/TechNet/samples/PS/Win98/Reskit/FILE/CLIP.EXE) and place it in your Windows system directory.

> **Steps:**
>
> 1. Open `regedit.exe`
> 2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/txtfile/shell` (This didn't work for me so I
>      had to put it under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell`, which makes it show up
>      in EVERY context menu)
> 3. Add a new key titled `copytoclip`
> 4. Set the default value of `copytoclip` to something like `Copy to
>      Clipboard`
> 5. Under `copytoclip`, add a key called `command`
> 6. Set the default value of `command` to `cmd /c clip < "%1"`

Now whenever you right click on a file, you should see a `Copy to Clipboard`option. What it does it that when you click on it, it will open a command prompt and run the `clip.exe` utility on the output piped from the file you selected.

Answer (score 1):

For XP I generally us the Send To X powertoy available from Microsoft.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751394.aspx

And while I'll probably go with Jin's answer which I also upvoted on Win7. One of the things I love about SendToX is the send to clipboard as name. I have probably averaged 4 uses per day of this since it came out with Win95.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to copy the text, just pipe the contents to the clipboard.

```
type file.txt | clip
```

Comment: This is a repeat of a small portion of the first answer –– from almost two years ago.

Comment: Actually the first answer does not use either the pipe "|" or the "type" keyword and the "<" operator is 'reserved for future use' in PowerShell and a few others. The method I suggest is also useful, different, and has the advantage of not requiring a registry edit...it just does what it should. Having a bad day Scott?

Comment: A fascinating tidbit of trivia, but irrelevant to this question.  Nothing here mentioned PowerShell until you brought it up.  `clip < file.txt` works fine in the Command Prompt, and it doesn’t require a registry edit unless the user wants to add it to the context menu –– and, since you haven’t said otherwise, I assume the same is true of your answer.  OK, I’ll concede that your answer is useful.  And, technically, it’s different –– the way a purple wheel differs from a black wheel.  It’s still a wheel.

Comment: I posted this method because the accepted answer does not work in my scenario... and the question (still) doesn't state a flavor of command prompt. My method doesn't depend on what prompt you use. So, this is just a wheel...the purple wheel only goes on the purple car. :)